# ROS Answers SE migration: neato xv11

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/neato_robot

does this node only work with neato xv11 or does it work with other neato products too (like the neato botvac series or the most recents robots in the xv series)?

thanks
dh

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185292/neato-xv11/) by [d](https://answers.ros.org/users/19443/d/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2014-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is only tested with the XV-11 (and in particular, the 2.0 firmware, although there is fork which is apparently updated to run better on the 3.1 firmware). However it is my understanding that most of the other products have a very similar serial interface. The serial interface is actually quite simple, so if you have some time and ability with Python, you might be able to make it work with newer Neato products.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0